# Make div fill out remaining vertical space of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the code below. I need the green div to always adjust its height, so to fill out the remaining space in the red div. I cannot use absolute positioning because of other functionality. I tried using height:100% but it is not working.[**Here is the demo.**](https://jsfiddle.net/njj3c5on/8/)

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-col">
      <p>Test content</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
       <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
      <p>longer</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-col">
      <p>Test content</p>
      <div id="yellow">I am yellow</div>
      <div id="green"><div id="white-border">
      i am blue
      </div></div>

      </div>

      </div>




    #container {
  overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
}
#left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  padding-bottom: 500em;
  margin-bottom: -500em;
}
#right-col {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -1px; /* Thank you IE */
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 500em;
  margin-bottom: -500em;
}
#yellow {
height: 20vw;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;

}

#green {
height: 100%;
  background-color: green;

}

#white-border {
width: 50%;
height: 5vw;
border: 1px solid white;

}
```

Comment: Make the containing div `position:relative` and the inner div `position:absolute` and then set the inner div to `left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0` and it will cover the entire size of the containing div. Or mix and match to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks, Robusto, but I do not want to increase the inner divs size. I do want the parent div to stretch down to the bottom of the red div.

Comment: Have you looked at Flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yes, but need compatibility for older browser versions.

Comment: In addition to flexbox, if you need browser compatibility, you could also use `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` cleverly to achieve this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/njj3c5on/9/ maybe like this?

Comment: I see no difference Paulius K.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to update, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/njj3c5on/10/

Comment: Thanks again, Paulius, at first glance it looks like you had it, but this actually makes green stretch lower than reds botton line. Because of reds overflow:hidden this is not visible, but does give me a problem. Any other solution that really makes green stretched to the bottom of red without overflowing it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/njj3c5on/24/ Maybe this fixes your problem? :D